# Batch insert PostgreSQL/Go

Tags: postgresql, go

I need to save multiple tags in the single query:

```
valueStrings := make([]string, 0, len(tags))
valueArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(tags) * 3)
for _, tag := range tags {
    valueStrings = append(valueStrings, "(?, ?, ?)")
    valueArgs = append(valueArgs, tag)
    valueArgs = append(valueArgs, "NOW()")
    valueArgs = append(valueArgs, "NOW()")
}
stmt := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO tags (name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES %s ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;", strings.Join(valueStrings, ", "))
c.DB.Exec(stmt, valueArgs...)
```

Checking PostgreSQL logs:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," at character 58
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO tags (name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I believe that `Exec` does not replace question marks with corresponding values.

> [Golang how do I batch sql statements with package database.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192138/1477118)

Comment: Is this just [**“Operator does not exist: integer =?” when using Postgres with Golang**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29887094/479863) in disguise? AFAIK the PostgreSQL interface for Go wants to use numbered placeholders (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...) instead of `?`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you:)